# Display selected geometry's name in div menu's title when right clicked

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

in my three.js scene I have 4 floors made using THREE.BoxGeometry. The floor's textures can be changed easily by right clicking on the individual floors and selecting an option from the div menu that appears.
My menu is on the html as:

```
<div id="menu" style="position:absolute;display:none;background-color:red">
  <span id="menuTitle" color="blue">menu</span>
  <br>
  <button id="35">Black Floor</button><br>
  <button id="36">Wood Floor</button><br>
  <button id="37">Blue Floor</button><br>
  <button id="38">Grey Floor</button>
</div>
```

my mouseDown function is as follows:

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var rightclick;
    if (!event) var event = window.event;
    if (event.which) rightclick = (event.which == 3);
    else if (event.button) rightclick = (event.button == 2);
  if (!rightclick) return;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
 

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4]);

  if (intersects.length) {
    intersect = intersects[0].object;
    menu.style.left = (event.clientX - rect.left) + "px";
    menu.style.top = (event.clientY - rect.top) + "px";
    document.getElementById("menuTitle").innerHTML = intersects[0].name;
    menu.style.display = "";
  }
  else{
    intersect = undefined;
  }
  
}
```

What I'm trying to do is change the inner HTML of "menuTitle" to floor1 when floor1 is right clicked (currently I'm getting "undefined") or better still a particular string (e.g. "Floor 1" when floor 1 is right clicked).
Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a small error in your code, instead of

```
document.getElementById("menuTitle").innerHTML = intersects[0].name;
```

it should be

```
document.getElementById("menuTitle").innerHTML = intersect.name;
```

The intersect objects in the returned array are not the same as the Object3D